# Location manager not updating location ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm trying to send the users location to a server when it updates (ideally every 100 meters), but for now I'm just trying to get it to work. I'm pretty new to iOS 7, so this probably isn't as hard as I'm making it seem... but here is the code I have

```
 -(void)sendUserLocationToServer
 {
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; //kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // The best you can get
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


NSLog(@"HELLO. Latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,   self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

 }


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"loactions %@", locations);
}
```

Basically, I have a method that calls sendUserLocationToServer which starts the location manager, and the plan is for it somehow tet down to the didUpdateLocations method and for now I just want to log out the location... but that is where I'll make the server calls once I get there.

In the logs, I get to the "HELLO" log, but it never gets down to the didUpdateLocations method.

What did I miss?

Thanks

EDIT: not sure if it makes a difference, but I have this in my app delegate which calls the process pushPushNotificationData method

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo{
NSLog(@"Received Notification: %@", responseInfo);

//Import the class header where the function is in this file (see above)
//Set class to variable
//Init the varibale / class
//Add the method you want to make public in the headerfile of responderViewController

XYZResponderViewController *responderController;
responderController = [[XYZResponderViewController alloc] init];

[responderController processPushNotificationData:responseInfo];



 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the delegate for your location manager (look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#jumpTo_4) for the docs).

Add this to your manager's initialization:

```
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
```

Of course, "self" has to conform to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol (look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) for apple's documentation.

Comment: I did that... it updates when I use the simulator, but when I try to run it on my phone it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the app have location services access enabled? Maybe when the App ran the first time you didn't give this permission.

Comment: Yea, it has permissions... it gets to the NSLog with the "HELLO" and the location... just doesn't update

Comment: Also, I did the locationManager setDeegate:self... still no good... i'll update my code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a delegate that needs to be set somewhere. 
locationManager:didUpdateLocations: looks like a typical delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

First add the Delegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Then when you initialize it in your .m controller, set the delegate:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
//[locationManager setDistanceFilter:10]; //kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone]; // whenever we move
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest]; // The best you can get
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And I don't know if this is what you need as well, but this is what I'm using...

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    float currentLocationLati = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate].latitude;
    float currentLocationLong = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate].longitude;
    NSLog(@"hAccuracy: %.1f, vAccuracy: %.1f", [[locations objectAtIndex:0] horizontalAccuracy], [[locations objectAtIndex:0] verticalAccuracy]);
    NSLog(@"Locations %@", [locations objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Comment: Yea, I have that... it works fine if I call the method from within it's own view controller... but if I call the method from the app Delegate when I get a push notification it doesn't work.

Comment: oh i see! what if you use the following afterwards? [responderController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: That threw an error in both my responderViewController and app delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "LocationTracker.h"

#define LATITUDE @"latitude"
#define LONGITUDE @"longitude"
#define ACCURACY @"theAccuracy"

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

@implementation LocationTracker
AppDelegate *objApp;


+ (CLLocationManager *)sharedLocationManager {
    static CLLocationManager *_locationManager;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_locationManager == nil) {
            _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        }
    }
    return _locationManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self==[super init]) {
        //Get the share model and also initialize myLocationArray
        self.shareModel = [LocationShareModel sharedModel];
        self.shareModel.myLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
        objApp = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    }
    return self;

}

-(void)applicationEnterBackground{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //Use the BackgroundTaskManager to manage all the background Task
    self.shareModel.bgTask = [BackgroundTaskManager sharedBackgroundTaskManager];
    [self.shareModel.bgTask beginNewBackgroundTask];
}

- (void) restartLocationUpdates
{
    NSLog(@"restartLocationUpdates");

    if (self.shareModel.timer) {
        [self.shareModel.timer invalidate];
        self.shareModel.timer = nil;
    }

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)startLocationTracking {
    NSLog(@"startLocationTracking");

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"locationServicesEnabled false");
        UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [servicesDisabledAlert show];
    } else {
        CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

        if(authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
            NSLog(@"authorizationStatus failed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"authorizationStatus authorized");
            CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

            if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
              [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
}


- (void)stopLocationTracking {
    NSLog(@"stopLocationTracking");

    if (self.shareModel.timer) {
        [self.shareModel.timer invalidate];
        self.shareModel.timer = nil;
    }

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    NSLog(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations");

    for(int i=0;i<locations.count;i++){
        CLLocation * newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
        CLLocationAccuracy theAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;

        NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if (locationAge > 30.0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //Select only valid location and also location with good accuracy
        if(newLocation!=nil&&theAccuracy>0
           &&theAccuracy<2000
           &&(!(theLocation.latitude==0.0&&theLocation.longitude==0.0))){

            self.myLastLocation = theLocation;
            self.myLastLocationAccuracy= theAccuracy;

            NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:theLocation.latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:theLocation.longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:theAccuracy] forKey:@"theAccuracy"];

            //Add the vallid location with good accuracy into an array
            //Every 1 minute, I will select the best location based on accuracy and send to server
            [self.shareModel.myLocationArray addObject:dict];
        }
    }

    //If the timer still valid, return it (Will not run the code below)
    if (self.shareModel.timer) {
        return;
    }

    self.shareModel.bgTask = [BackgroundTaskManager sharedBackgroundTaskManager];
    [self.shareModel.bgTask beginNewBackgroundTask];

    //Restart the locationMaanger after 1 minute
    self.shareModel.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(restartLocationUpdates)
                                                           userInfo:nil
                                                            repeats:NO];

    //Will only stop the locationManager after 10 seconds, so that we can get some accurate locations
    //The location manager will only operate for 10 seconds to save battery
    if (self.shareModel.delay10Seconds) {
        [self.shareModel.delay10Seconds invalidate];
        self.shareModel.delay10Seconds = nil;
    }

    self.shareModel.delay10Seconds = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];

}


//Stop the locationManager
-(void)stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"locationManager stop Updating after 10 seconds");
}


- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
   // NSLog(@"locationManager error:%@",error);

    switch([error code])
    {
        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please check your network connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enable Location Service" message:@"You have to enable the Location Service to use this App. To enable, please go to Settings->Privacy->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        default:
        {

        }
            break;
    }
}


//Send the location to Server
- (void)updateLocationToServer {

    NSLog(@"updateLocationToServer");

    // Find the best location from the array based on accuracy
    NSMutableDictionary * myBestLocation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<self.shareModel.myLocationArray.count;i++){
        NSMutableDictionary * currentLocation = [self.shareModel.myLocationArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(i==0)
            myBestLocation = currentLocation;
        else{
            if([[currentLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue]<=[[myBestLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue]){
                myBestLocation = currentLocation;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"My Best location:%@",myBestLocation);


    //If the array is 0, get the last location
    //Sometimes due to network issue or unknown reason, you could not get the location during that  period, the best you can do is sending the last known location to the server
    if(self.shareModel.myLocationArray.count==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get location, use the last known location");

        self.myLocation=self.myLastLocation;
        self.myLocationAccuracy=self.myLastLocationAccuracy;

    }else{
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theBestLocation;
        theBestLocation.latitude =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LATITUDE]floatValue];
        theBestLocation.longitude =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LONGITUDE]floatValue];
        self.myLocation=theBestLocation;
        self.myLocationAccuracy =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"Send to Server: Latitude(%f) Longitude(%f) Accuracy(%f)",self.myLocation.latitude, self.myLocation.longitude,self.myLocationAccuracy);







    //TODO: Your code to send the self.myLocation and self.myLocationAccuracy to your server

    //After sending the location to the server successful, remember to clear the current array with the following code. It is to make sure that you clear up old location in the array and add the new locations from locationManager
    [self.shareModel.myLocationArray removeAllObjects];
    self.shareModel.myLocationArray = nil;
    self.shareModel.myLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}




@end
```

Comment: I hope this code will work for you. I have tried with many codes for location manger. This one is the most accurate.